# sybase load data incorrect syntax

Tags: load, sybase, sap-ase

This is my first attempt to load data to a sybase table from an external file. Here is my code snippet.

I create the table as below..

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.TEST_DATA') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.TEST_DATA
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_DATA
    (
      NAME            CHAR (10) NOT NULL
    , ID         CHAR (4) NULL
    )   
GO
```

This is how I try to load the data..

```
LOAD TABLE dbo.TEST_DATA
( 
NAME,ID 
) 
FROM 'C:\testdata.txt'
DELIMITED BY ','
```

The data in the file is simple..

```
xxxxxxx,1111
yyyyy,2222
```

When I try to load the data, it gives me "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword TABLE" error. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  Please be specify which Sybase product(ASE? IQ? SQL Anywhere?, etc), and version you are referring to, as syntax can vary between products.

Comment: Hi Michael, its ASE. version 15.0

Comment: Then my answer should be correct for you

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you did not specify Product, my guess is you are using Sybase ASE.

The syntax listed above is for Sybase IQ.

To load a table in ASE from a flat file, you should use the `bcp` utility.

It would look something like this:

```
bcp [DATABASE]..TEST_DATA in testdata.txt -S servername -U username -P password -c -t ,
```

The `-c` specifies that the file is plaintext, and `-t ,` specifies the column delimiter (default is tab).

More information can be found in the bcp section of the [Sybase ASE Utility Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/utility78.htm) It's from the ASE 15.5 docs, but the syntax is the same for most versions 12.0 and newer.